# Equivalent JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to javascript and wondering what is the equivalent javascript syntax for below Java Code.

```
public static void crcValue(byte[] value) {
    byte crc = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        crc = (byte) (value[i] + crc);
    }
    value[15] = (byte) (crc & 255);
}
```

I have tried the below code.

```js
var cmd = new ArrayBuffer(16);
function crcValue(cmd){
    var crc;
    for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
          crc = cmd[i] + crc;
    }
    cmd[16] = crc & 255 ;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you now javascript or you're waiting for someone to "translate" it to Javascript for you?

Comment: I have tried below code var cmd = new ArrayBuffer(16);

      function crcValue(cmd){
        var crc;
        for (var i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
              crc = cmd[i] + crc;
        }
        cmd[16] = crc & 255 ;
      }

Comment: Can you explain what this code is supposed to do? Why isn't the attempt working? What was expected and what are you getting? Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: I am using noblejs to communicate with bluetooth device, which required 16 byte data payload to write. Last byte will be CRC computation.